# Чи є в українській мові слово "заключати" (про договір)?

Tags: вживання-слів

Час від часу ми використовуємо таке словосполучення як "заключати угоду, договір". Але філологи кажуть, що в українській мові такого слова взагалі немає, бо "контракти укладають", "договір підписують"...

Comment: Було б добре якби ви процитували цих філологів, і вказали чому ви сумніваєтесь в їх думці.

Comment: Моя колега запевняє, що слово "заключати" є калькою. Але ж в одному із видань на днях прочитала: "Аби заключити договір на газопостачання, споживачам не треба стояти в чергах..."

Answer (score 3):

Часто люди використовують словосполучення ***"заключити договір"***, проте це не правильно.

Зокрема на сайті  **[Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/uklasti-ugodu-pidpisati-dogovir)** є чудова картинка, яка демонструє, як правильно говорити. 
[image: угода]

**[OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80/)** дає пораду: *"Замініть скальковану конструкцію **заключити договір** на правильний варіант: **укласти угоду, підписати договір**."*

Answer (score 1):

Гадаю в таких випадках можна користуватися [Словником-атисуржиком](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=19&t=483), який дає варіанти "укласти угоду" та "підписати договір". Про це ж пише на [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/45/53399/299867.html).

Також [тут](http://moz.gov.ua/jak-uklasti-dogovir-z-likarem) і [тут](http://gukr.com/article859.html) знайшов такий варіант як "укласти договір", однак я не впевнений, що цим джерелам можна довіряти (хоча один із них сайт МОЗ), а тому не знаю чи це правильний варіант.